# Function accepts Laravel collection object although only string is allowed

Tags: laravel

I have just encountered a problem where I can't explain why this works.

I have a function that only accepts string type parameters.

**Example class**

```php
class A {

    public function __construct() {
        $data = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection(); 
        // getType($data) => object
        $this->make($data);
    }

    private function make(string $str): string {
        // getType($str) => string
        ...
    }
}
```

**Question:** Why can I pass a collection even though only string is allowed?

Comment: Did you actually pass in the object itself or did you pass along a cllable type (which is actually a string literal). For example, if the calling code were to execute on the callable type in such a fashion as `call_user_func_array` you would have a callable type hint that is also in the form of a string literal.

Comment: Is the behaviour similar when you test with standard PHP classes, instead of Laravel collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this behaviour you can add on top in your PHP class: `declare(strict_types=1);`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php), php will try to convert it:

> By default, PHP will coerce values of the wrong type into the expected scalar type declaration if possible. For example, a function that is given an int for a parameter that expects a string will get a variable of type string.

But if you re-run you code with `declare(strict_types=1);`, you will get `TypeError` message.

Answer (score 1):

An empty collection is, per definition, an empty array. It then passes your method due to PHP's **Type Juggling**. This means that during the comparison of variables of different types, PHP will first convert them to a common, comparable type, which in this case will convert the array to a string.

This can be avoided by type casting your variables, or by declaring strict types.

You can find more information on the PHP documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php